# zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available when running script in Blender 2.43

Tags: python, scripting, export, import, conversion

when I try to execute an export script using `Blender -P C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\Testing4.py` in the cmd on Blender 2.43(Python 2.4), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "Testing4.py", line 3, in ?
  File "C:\blender-2.43-windows\.blender\scripts\flt_import.py", line 86, in ?
    import os
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Error executing Python script from command-line:
```

which I don't seem to understand. I ran the script inside the Blender app script window and it works fine but not inside command prompt. Has anyone encountered this error before?

Edit:

Here is my import export conversion(Testing4.py) script:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)

import Blender
import flt_import 
import export_obj





flt_import.select_file(r'C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\sg_navysoldier.flt')
out_file=export_obj.write_ui(r'C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\HUH1.obj')
```

Here is what I see in my console when I execute `Blender -P C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\Testing4.py`:

[image]

Comment: Might be more useful for you to ask how the thing you are trying to do is done with the current version. There might not be a lot of people here who would use a version from literally 15 years ago...

Comment: can you put `import sys; print(sys.executable)` at the top of your script and see if it is running the same python .exe in the blender app as the command prompt?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I managed to create an import/export script with the latest version. However, I need the flt_import.py which is only available at Blender 2.4x versions.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Hi, I have edited the results in, but it seems that I can only see the Blender version since I think Python is embedded in Blender.

Comment: Can you try installing [zlib](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) for windows and see if that works? From what I can tell the older versions of Blender don't come packaged with their own version of Python, and rely on whatever version the system has installed. At least when I download the archived version of 2.43 i cannot find any Python.exe or interpreter in that file. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: These issues seem to be related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060799/zlib-module-missing-python-2-4-3)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999217/cant-fix-zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available) 
[3](https://trendoceans.com/how-to-solve-zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available/) 
Though it seems the  issue is far more prevalent on Linux than Windows. In any case the solution seems to figure out how to install that `zlib1g-dev` package.